# NullPointerException with Scanner

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

I am getting a NullPointerException on the 5th line. I am not really sure why or how to fix it...

```
    public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console){
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner file = null;
    String userInputFile = null;
    while (file.equals(null)) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
            userInputFile = inputFile.nextLine();
            file = new Scanner(new File(userInputFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print(userInputFile + " (No such file or directory)");
            file = null;
            return file;
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: What is the point of passing `console` as argument of your method if you are not using it, but instead are creating separate `Scanner`?

Answer (score 6):

Although you generally compare Java objects using the `equals` method, `null` comparison is a notable exception: no Java `Object` compares `equal` to `null` - Java classes need to satisfy this [requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> For any non-null reference value x, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Moreover, `file` is `null` to start with, so calling any methods on it, including `equals`, will result in NPE.

Therefore, you need to use reference equality instead:

```
while (file == null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fifth line, you have `while (file.equals(null))`, which attempts to call the `equals` method on `file`. However, you explicitly set that variable to null on the third line: `Scanner file = null;`, which will of course result in the NullPointerException you received when any method on it is used.

If you want to check whether the variable is null, you must not attempt to call any method on it - use `while (file != null)` instead. (With your current code, nothing in the `while` will ever execute because you never initialized `file`.)

Answer (score 0):

In line 5 you are using variable file which is set to null in line 3.
You need to set a variable to a non null value before you can call methods on it.